# Return the relationships when querying paths

Tags: neo4j

I'm using the following query to get all paths between nodes in my DB:

```
match p=()-[r:CALLS]-() return p
```

This returns a list of `p`, with each `p` containing the `start` and `end` nodes.

However, the relationships between nodes are not in the response.

How can I get the nodes *and* the relationships between those nodes in the response?

Answer (score 0):

The path `p` is a sequence of nodes and relationships, your query is correct. The relationships may "look" empty if they contain no properties.

Answer (score -1):

You have to give names to the parts that you want to return, so try this:

```
MATCH (p:)-[r:]-(q:)
RETURN p,r,q
```

Depending on the size of your DB, this could be quite large. You can further reduce the size by specifying node types and relationship types after the colons in the query.

edit: 
It follows that you could return only the relationship by replacing the 2nd line with `RETURN r`